# How to extract readable source code from a .web file?

Tags: latex, pascal, metafont

I'm trying to dig into the source for Donald Knuth's Metafont compiler.  However, I am getting bogged down in his toolchain.  What is the best way to extract readable, navigable, source code from one of Knuth's .web files?  I am toying with doing a reimplementation in another language, and I want to look some at the geometric algorithms, etc... so I have some idea what I am getting into.

The .web -> .tex -> .dvi route left me with a huge document without an index, that is terribly slow to render, at least in evince.

The .web -> .p file resulted in source code that was stripped of all comments, and deliberately packed without any consideration for readability.

Should I start messing around with pascal pretty printers? Use a pascal-> C converter like modern latex does and then pretty print and explore that?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of `WEB` is that the program source code *is* readable in the `.web` source itself, or in the documentation (produced using `weave *.web`-> `pdftex *.tex`).

The program code (generated by `tangle *.web`) is intended just for the computer, not for humans.